# Docker: container can't find domain on private network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to figure out a problem with identical docker containers being run on different hosts, where one container can find/ping/nslookup a domain on a private network, and another can't. One host is OSX 10.11, the other is Ubuntu 16.04. Both are running docker 1.12. I'm using `docker-compose` to bring up my application, and I'm hoping to figure out what is going on and how to fix it, or some configuration changes I could make without resorting to hardcoding domains or ip addresses that would make the container behave the same on both hosts.

On my OSX box, I have the following dns nameservers set automatically by my domain:

```
osx:$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain redacted.lan
nameserver 172.16.20.19
nameserver 10.43.0.11
```

*I'm aware that `resolv.conf` isn't used by most OSX tools, but System Preferences > Network shows the same settings.*

I have similar settings on my Ubuntu 16 box as well (command from https://askubuntu.com/questions/152593/command-line-to-list-dns-servers-used-by-my-system):

```
ubu:$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search redacted.lan

ubu:$ nmcli device show eno1 | grep IP4.DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.16.20.19
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.43.0.11
```

Then, on both OSX and Ubuntu, I start my container with this:

```
$ docker run -it redacted_web bash
```

And then I run these commands to diagnose my problem:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y dnsutils
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
$ nslookup redacted.lan
```

On OSX, the output from the last 2 commands is:

```
root@d19f49322fda:/app# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search local
nameserver 192.168.65.1
root@d19f49322fda:/app# nslookup redacted.lan
Server:     192.168.65.1
Address:    192.168.65.1#53

Name:   redacted.lan
Address: 172.18.0.23
```

On Ubuntu, the output is:

```
root@91e82d652e07:/app# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
search redacted.lan

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
root@91e82d652e07:/app# nslookup redacted.lan 
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find redacted.lan: NXDOMAIN
```

Possible differences I can think of:

- On OSX there is a vm running docker, where as on ubuntu it's native
- On Ubuntu, docker is run with `sudo`, possibly picking up different configuration settings

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Very well written description of the problem. Shame there's not a simple fix yet, other than disabling dnsmasq.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer (2017-06-20)**

Newer versions of Ubuntu (17.04+) don't use dnsmasq (it now uses systemd-resolved). You'll run into a similar problem with host resolution, but the original solution here no longer works. In fact, Docker containers can't even communicate with systemd-resolvd because it's running its own DNS in a location that's unreachable from within a container.

A good solution on newer versions of Ubuntu is to put the following configuration in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (create this file if it doesn't exist):

```
{
    "dns": ["172.16.20.19", "10.43.0.11"],
    "dns-search": ["redacted.lan"]
}
```

This allows you to configure the DNS servers and search domains. The DNS IPs above are from the original question, but you can use your own custom ones too. You probably want to match the DNS config on your host machine. Search domain is optional, and you could entirely omit that line (careful with your commas!). Again, you probably want to match your host machine.

Essentially, what these daemon.json options do, is automatically inject the DNS config and search domain into the config files inside the container for any container that is started on that daemon. This is necessary because you cannot use systemd-resolved from the host to resolve DNS within the container due to limitations of the way systemd-resolved works. The docs are [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#bind-docker-to-another-hostport-or-a-unix-socket) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/).

---

**Original Answer**

The problem is that the host is using dnsmasq to resolve the private IP and Docker is not using dnsmasq on the host.

The simple fix is to **turn off dnsmasq** on the host machine.

1. Run `sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
2. Comment out this line: `#dns=dnsmasq`
3. Run `sudo service network-manager restart`

Now, you should be able to use the docker container and it will resolve your private DNS correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check your startup scripts for the docker daemon, it includes the following option to adjust the DNS used when creating containers:

```
$ dockerd --help
# ...
  --dns=[]                                 DNS server to use
  --dns-opt=[]                             DNS options to use
  --dns-search=[]                          DNS search domains to use
```

On Ubuntu, I believe these settings are in /etc/default/docker which is read by /etc/init.d/docker. Leaving these unset should default to the /etc/resolv.conf values.

---

Update: [Docker's DNS networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) documentation has a lot of detail that should point you in the right direction.

> if there are no more nameserver entries left in the container’s /etc/resolv.conf file, the daemon adds public Google DNS nameservers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) to the container’s DNS configuration.

This looks like it's probably happening in your situation. The filters are looking for local addresses, which I wouldn't think is happening in your situation with a 172.16.0.0/12 private addr, but it's possible.

> You might wonder what happens when the host machine’s /etc/resolv.conf
>   file changes. The docker daemon has a file change notifier active
>   which will watch for changes to the host DNS configuration.
>
> > Note: The file change notifier relies on the Linux kernel’s inotify
> >     feature. Because this feature is currently incompatible with the
> >     overlay filesystem driver, a Docker daemon using “overlay” will not be
> >     able to take advantage of the /etc/resolv.conf auto-update feature.

If this is happening, then giving the daemon a restart would likely resolve it and would indicate you want Docker to start after the NetworkManager.

---

Update #2: looking over [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/541) it's possible that they also included 172.16.0.0/12 to avoid conflicts with docker's bridged networks. If you can be sure to avoid using the same network inside docker, then passing the dns server in /etc/defaults/docker would likely force the correct behavior. There's also a mention at the end of the post about lxc causing conflicts, so if you have that installed and can remove it, give that a try first.

Comment: There don't seem to be any settings applied in the default: `$ cat /etc/default/docker 

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"`

All of the settings are commented out.

Comment: Following up on the edits: then could this be an actual docker bug? My Ubuntu install is out of the box 16.04, and it appears that the `127.0.1.1` nameserver is a `dnsmasq` instance, so if that was added somewhere between 14 and 16 and docker is filtering out `127.` nameservers it means that the default behavior for Ubuntu 16 isn't working with default docker.

Comment: I don't know if they'd consider this a bug with Docker, maybe with a Ubuntu package of Docker. Should be easily worked around with some extra configuration, either by yourself or the Ubuntu package.

Comment: Hmmm... I just recreated this using a fresh/default ubuntu 14 and the same thing happened. The "solution" seems to be to disable dnsmasq in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, but if things aren't working out of the box for whatever reason, I'd consider that a bug... at the very least it might help someone else not get blocked for hours

Comment: I'm having the same problem - is disabling dnsmasq the best solution for this? Any equally simple solutions that don't involve disabling dnsmasq?

Comment: @mkasberg the initial answer above gives the option to override the DNS in the dockerd cli.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't been able to get that to work after about half an hour of messing with various options. Are there specific steps to just make Docker play nice with dnsmasq on the host?