# wget (or any connection) inside docker can't connect to servers own ip address

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose, wget

I'm trying to use wget within a docker container to connect to my servers own ip address to download an image **but it currently times out and never connects.**

[image]

If I use localhost as the address to my image then I can access the image, however, my setup has two websites (one for dev and one for live).  localhost can only map to one of these instances and so I can only access the livesite (since that is mapped also to localhost as default).

[image]

Therefore I need a way to actually connect to the ip address of my own server (or even better use my actual domain names which will route to the correct folders via apahce, which also don't work right now since connecting to my own IP address doesn't work from within the container).

**How can I get this to work? Or | What might be causing the issue?**

***Things I've tried:***

Connecting to the host machine it can talk to its own ip address just fine.  Its from within the container that it can't seem to do this? (Notice when I execute my commands I'm doing it on the container directly and not the host machine)

I verified file is also there from other machines and the image is present and can be connected to.  Even docker on my own machine in its own container can access the servers image fine.

**This led me to conclude that if the container is pointing to the ip address of the host machine itself then it will fail by timeout.**

**Docker-Compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
    dblive:
        image: mysql:5.5.52
        volumes:
            - ./db_data_live:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ******
            MYSQL_USER: ******
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******

    dbdev:
        image: mysql:5.5.52
        volumes:
            - ./db_data_dev:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ********
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ******
            MYSQL_USER: *****
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******

    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - dblive
            - dbdev
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        environment:
            PMA_ARBITRARY : 1
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8081:80"

    web:
        #build: ./
        depends_on:
            - dblive
            - dbdev
        image: poolservice/distribution:latest
        volumes:
            - ./web:/var/www
            - ./config/custom.php.ini:/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/custom.php.ini
            - ./logs/apache_error.log:/var/log/apache2/error.log
            - ./logs/apache_access.log:/var/log/apache2/access.log
            - ./config/apache_default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
            - ./config/apache_default-ssl.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
            - ./config/ssl/apache.key:/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
            - ./config/ssl/apache.crt:/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
            - ./web/public_html/livesite:/app
            - ./web/public_html/devsite:/appdev
        restart: always
        ports: 
            #Standard HTTP Port
            - "80:80"
            #Below allows access to local computer from outside ports
            - "8080:80"
            #SSH Port
            - "443:443"
            #Below allows access to local computer from outside ports
            - "4443:443"
```

Comment: Please let me know ASAP why the downvote, I believe I have showed everything necessary for a good question including attempts I have made.  Updating now to add more details.  I also included the docker-compose.yml file as reference

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is similar to mine or maybe same issue worded differently? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902786/docker-container-cant-find-domain-on-private-network?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer!

In the docker-compose file I added these commands for my domain names to access the localhost.

```
extra_hosts:
            - "domain.com:127.0.0.1"
            - "dev.domain.tech:127.0.0.1"
```